# Docker Compose Could not open file build: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After moving my docker project on my disc I can no longer run it.  Whenever I try to run `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up` I get an error

```
Could not open file build: No such file or directory
```

I've tried purging all docker resources but am still receiving this error.

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

How can I either purge all docker data entirely, or fix the issue after moving my project?

My docker-compose.yml is unedited from [this project's dc file](https://github.com/18F/docker-compose-django-react).

Comment: can you show your yaml files

Comment: @Coding Added it.  It's unedited from the boilerplate I cloned from.

Comment: You've maintained the folder structure for the project, right?

Comment: @Bardia yea I just copied the folder from my downloads folder to my projects folder and renamed the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prune all docker data on the system by using the command `docker system prune`.

Comment: That worked, which is weird cause I already ran that too and it cleared 0B when I just ran it again.